# integrating hadoop, revo-scaleR and hive

Tags: r, hadoop, hive, revolution-r

I have a requirement to fetch data from HIVE tables into a csv file and use it in RevoScaleR.
Currently we pull the data from HIVE and manually put it into a file and use it in unix file system for adhoc analysis, however, the requirement is to re-direct the result directly into hdfs location and use RevoScaleR from there?

How do I do that? or what sort of connection do I need to establish this.

Comment: See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ImportExport

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correct, you could use RevoScaleR ODBC connection to import HIVE table and do further analysis from there.

Here is example of using Hortonworks provided ODBC driver:

```
OdbcConnString <- "DSN=Sample Hortonworks Hive DSN"

odbcDS <- RxOdbcData(sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM airline",
                                connectionString=OdbcConnString,
                                stringsAsFactors=TRUE, 
                                useFastRead = TRUE,
                                rowsPerRead=150000)

xdfFile <- "airlineHWS.xdf"

if(file.exists(xdfFile)) file.remove(xdfFile)                       

Flights<-rxImport(odbcDS, outFile=xdfFile,overwrite=TRUE)

rxGetInfo(data="airlineHWS.xdf", getVarInfo=TRUE,numRows = 10)
```

Comment: Where can I find the correct string to put into OdbcConnString? How does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Chenwei's approach is ok but there is just one problem. The data is temporarily stored in memory as data frame in odbcDS object. If we have huge table in hive, then we are done.

I would suggested to keep everything on disk by using external tables in hive and then using the backend data directly in revolution r.

Something in these lines:

1. Create external table from the existing hive tables in textfile(csv, tab etc) format.

   > CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ext_table
   >
   > LIKE your_original_table_name
   >
   > ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
   >
   > LOCATION '/your/hdfs/location';

   Here we are creating external table which is stored as csv file in hdfs.
2. Next copy the original table to the external table using insert overwrite command.

   > insert overwrite table ext_table select * from your_original_table_name

   If we want to check the backend data on hdfs type:

   > hadoop fs -ls /your/hdfs/location/

   We can see the part files stored at the location. Go ahead and cat them to be double sure
3. Now we can use RxTextData function to read the data from above step as

   > hive_data <- RxTextData(file='/your/hdfs/location/', delimiter = ',')

   Now you can create an xdf file using hive_data as inFile argument in RxXdfData to be more efficient for further processing but above all data has never touched memory.